# JDT ASTParser to get the value of a string field

Tags: eclipse, parsing, eclipse-jdt, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to use jdt ASTParser to get the value of a String field declared in a java file. Actually what I need is to resolve any possible dependencies from other classes e.g.
public String str = "somethig"+SomeTherClass.SOMETHING_ELSE.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out ...it was quite simple actually ..here's the code:

```
ICompilationUnit cu = ....
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setSource(cu);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
ASTNode node = parser.createAST(null);
node.accept(new YourVisitor());
```

Then in your implementation of the ASTVisitor you need to call resolveConstantExpressionValue() on the node being visited.